# Enable support for HTTP methods in an Apache HTTP Server

Tags: http, httpd, curl

I am sending a PUT request using curl and getting a 405 Method Not Allowed status code. I commented out the `<Limit>` directive in `httpd.conf` file but still seeing this error.

### CURL request sending by me

```
curl -w "OFB:return-code=%{http_code}:time-total=%{time_total}::OFE"  -g -v \
     --cert /tmp/2k.pem --key /tmp/2k.key --limit-rate 0 -o output.gz \
     -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -X PUT  http://[2010::102]/sw_compression/ht.html
```

### Response getting

```
> PUT /sw_compression/ht.html HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: [2010::102]
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip
> 
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Date: Thu, 16 Feb 2017 09:03:09 GMT
* Server Apache/2.2.22 (Fedora) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Fedora)
< Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS,TRACE
< Content-Length: 400
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
{ [data not shown]
100   400  100   400    0     0  39062      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 44444
```

Comment: Did you restart httpd after making the config change ?

Comment: yes... I am restarting the httpd.
I got the solution. Actually we need to  a php file that insert a PUT or any http header in the response